# What is the point to have facade with dynamically created monobehaviors

Tags: zenject

I'm learning about factories in Zenject and everything is quit simple. However, I have a question.

> Using FromSubContainerResolve can be particularly useful if your
> dynamically created object has a lot of its own dependencies. You can
> have it behave like a "Facade" (see the subcontainers section for
> details on nested containers / facades)

When we instantiate MonoBehaviour objects dynamically, we can inject onto them with factories, but what is the point to instantiate them from a subcontainer because we will not able to inject this facade class to any entities. This means that we will not be able to get any of instantiated objects sub classes too through [inject] anyway.

Example of dynamicly created object

- Ship [Monobehaviour]
- - HealthHandler [Monobehaviour]

If I understood correctly, I will not be able to inject neither health handler or ship to another entity anyway. Whats the point to have ship like facade if its sub-object is already closed for entire object graph.

I created ship facade and instantiate it via Zenject. I thought that it will be injected to any other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found answer after wrote question down here :)
If I understood correctly we would need dynamicly create MonoBehaviour with factories from subcontainer only for one reason.

To get unique instances to work with inside GameObject container.
We can register health system in GameObject container and each game object with this container will have unique instance of health system. Am I right?